# Why doesn't work a anonim function as a function's argument for default value?

Tags: javascript

everyone!
I had written a function for get user's name. I had used anonim function as function's argument for default value. I don't understand - why doesn't work for me?

```
function printName(name = function(){
    return prompt('What is your name?', '');
}){
    console.log(name);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to call the function in `console.log`? E.g.: `console.log(name());`? Otherwise you need to describe what you mean by "doesn't work"

Comment: @UnholySheep I hade written about anonim function for default value. If I call printName() without arguments I watch in console: 
ƒ (){
    return prompt('What is your name?', '');
}

Comment: @UnholySheep and I don't watch function's job prompt()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is slightly unclear what you are confused about, I suspect that you want to call the anonymous function.
Presumably like this

```js
function printName(name = function(){
    return prompt('What is your name?', '');
}()){
    console.log(name);
}

printName();
```

Note the extra pair of parenthesis after the closing brace of the anonymous function expression

Comment: it's worked. Thanks! But why couple of  parenthesis after closing brace?

Comment: Those are for invoking the function immediately. See this page for more info about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE